# Database Error while updating the ci_session? I am using mulitiple Database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, multiple-databases

> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table `buz85ftp_buzoonga2.ci_sessions` doesn't exist

```
UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1468474888, `user_data` = 'a:11:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"userid\";s:3:\"670\";s:5:\"phone\";s:10:\"9956451235\";s:7:\"emailid\";s:15:\"tester@test.com\";s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Tester\";s:8:\"usertype\";s:1:\"1\";s:16:\"user_country_ref\";s:3:\"673\";s:12:\"user_country\";s:1:\"0\";s:9:\"time_zone\";s:12:\"Asia/Kolkata\";s:14:\"user_logged_in\";b:1;s:17:\"flash:new:success\";s:56:\"
```

> Message(s) deleted
>
> \";}' WHERE `session_id` = 'f171da0c9be6fa5eb8d32905c8e1251b'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 288

```
function sess_write()
    {
        // Are we saving custom data to the DB?  If not, all we do is update the cookie
        if ($this->sess_use_database === FALSE)
        {
            $this->_set_cookie();
            return;
        }

        // set the custom userdata, the session data we will set in a second
        $custom_userdata = $this->userdata;
        $cookie_userdata = array();

        // Before continuing, we need to determine if there is any custom data to deal with.
        // Let's determine this by removing the default indexes to see if there's anything left in the array
        // and set the session data while we're at it
        foreach (array('session_id','ip_address','user_agent','last_activity') as $val)
        {
            unset($custom_userdata[$val]);
            $cookie_userdata[$val] = $this->userdata[$val];
        }

        // Did we find any custom data?  If not, we turn the empty array into a string
        // since there's no reason to serialize and store an empty array in the DB
        if (count($custom_userdata) === 0)
        {
            $custom_userdata = '';
        }
        else
        {
            // Serialize the custom data array so we can store it
            $custom_userdata = $this->_serialize($custom_userdata);
        }
        // Run the update query
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));

        // Write the cookie.  Notice that we manually pass the cookie data array to the
        // _set_cookie() function. Normally that function will store $this->userdata, but
        // in this case that array contains custom data, which we do not want in the cookie.
        $this->_set_cookie($cookie_userdata);
    }
```

Comment: While deleting a record i am getting this error. Data is getting deleted but im facing this error?

Comment: The buz85ftp_buzoonga2 database doesn't contain ci_sessions table. You need to create the table manually. You can read more detail in the [database driver](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) section of the docs.

Comment: ci_sessions is exists in buz85ftp_buzoonga1 database. i want to switch the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->CI->load->database('databasename', TRUE);
```

Comment: I don't think this is good way to answer. only shooting the code without any formatting and without any explanation

Answer (score 0):

Create a table named `ci_sessions` then try again

Comment: ci_sessions is exists in buz85ftp_buzoonga1 database. i want to switch the database :(

Comment: `buz85ftp_buzoonga1` should be your default database, so, CI will be able to access it via `$this->db`. To access another database you can create a new connection like this `$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);`. Also, you can use existing connection and switch database like this `$this->db->db_select('<your database name>');`